# Update panel postback on Internet explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, updatepanel, postback

I have an update panel and inside that I have a repeater and a button.

On button click it filters some data and binds the repeater.

Everything is working fine on local host. On server, everything is working perfectly in chrome, firefox, safari, but in Internet explorer it does a full postback.

I tried with putting button click in

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnupdaetd" />
</Triggers>
```

But to no effect. Except Internet explorer, on each browser everything is working fine.

I even tried

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

with no luck.

Nothing is wrong in code, as everything is working perfectly in  chrome, firefox, safari. The only issue is with Internet explorer in server. On local it's working in internet explorer too.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnupdaetd" />
```

to

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnupdaetd" EventName="Click" />
```

and add `ClientIDMode` to `AutoID` on your asp button like this

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnupdaetd" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Text="Click" OnClick="btnupdaetd_Click"  />
```

also in your update panel add `UpdateMode="Conditional"` like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

Comment: ClientIDMode="AutoID" stopped event clicked, nothing working then

Comment: Its not working only on IE on server, rest on each browser its working perfectly

Comment: please share your code and what is the version of your IE?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in Code, and version i checked is 11 even i tried to change it in lower version

Comment: well if nothing is wrong in code then it should work in IE for sure, however if its not working then there must be some problem and it would be very good if you can share your code as chances of getting the correct answer to your problem may increase.